# Storing data into list within a list based on class

Tags: c#, list, object

Lets say I have the following class:

```
public class name()
{ 
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string LastName{ get; set; }

   public List<ItemOwner> ItemOwners { get; set; }

   public name()
   {
      this.ItemOwners = new List<ItemOwner>();
   }
} 
public class ItemOwner()
{ 
   public string nameofcat { get; set; }
   public string nameofsomething { get; set; }

   public List<AddressofCat> AddressofCats{ get; set; }

   public ItemOwner()
   {
      this.AddressofCats = new List<AddressofCat>();
   }
} 
public class AddressofCat()
{ 
   public string streetaddress{ get; set; }
   public string country { get; set; }

}
```

I have made a call to the database and have recieved the populated class as an object.

```
 var returnedcatobject = //select from database
```

I now wish to add an additional cataddress to the list:

```
 var newcataddress = new AddressofCat();
 newcataddress.streetaddress = "Randomaddress";
 newcataddress.country = "Rhodesia";
```

Done now we have a new list of cat addresses and I want to add them to the returned catobject.

How would I do this ?

Comment: What type `returnedcatobject` is?

Comment: class object from the db

Comment: I am making a call to mongo db , the returned object is a object from the database based on the class....

Comment: @user1264626: what class exactly? Post its declaration.

Comment: var returnedcatobject = = repo.Single(c => c.nameofcat == "sam");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if returnedcatobject is of type `List<AddressofCat>` then like this:

```
 var newcataddress = new AddressofCat();
 newcataddress.streetaddress = "Randomaddress";
 newcataddress.country = "Rhodesia";

returnedcatobject.Add(newcataddress);
```